# JQuery XML and CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cdata

I'm **using JQuery** to parse XML string because I need **to navigate through DOM** then **and get changed content**. I see JQuery as the best tool for this task.

rawXML string:

```
<Root>
  <Text Title='my "best" text'><![CDATA[ Yes & No ]]></Text>
</Root>
```

Here is the way I get object:

```
let xml = $($.parseXML(rawXML)).find('Root');
```

So there are some troubles for me getting content with `html()` function:

1) it removes all `CDATA` with text inside*

2) it replaces single quotes of attr values to double

this code

```
console.log($($.parseXML('<Root><Text Title=\'my "best" text\'><![CDATA[ Yes & No ]]></Text></Root>')).find('Root').html());
```

returns `<Text Title="my &quot;best&quot; text"></Text>`

*I can solve this by replacing `<![CDATA[` with `<Cdata>` but the error occures because of `&`.

May be there are more issues caused by xml->html trasforming.

How can I preserve all my XML "as is" and navigate through DOM?

I prefer to use JQuery because the result of my code is API for users, who want to use it =)

P.S. This is VSCode extension (Node.js)

Thank you for any solutions!

**UPD**

The main problem is that **I need to have the original XML** from string (It is valid), with all its quotes, CDATAs etc.

Comment: I'd imagine most problems are caused by the fact that your XML isn't valid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, my XML example is valid, isn't it?

Comment: Now you added the missing `[`, although I'd suggest you stick to using double quotes to delimit the values and escape those inside values, like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root><Text Title="my &quot;best&quot; text"><![CDATA[Yes & No]]</Text></Root>`

Comment: `&quot;` is a perfectly valid HTML representation of `'` and I cannot reproduce the second issue. Can you please edit the question an add a full snippet that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Or better yet, get rid of the unnecessary CDATA completely and encode the `&` yourself: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root><Text Title="my &quot;best&quot; text">Yes &amp; No</Text></Root>`

Comment: Your last edit finally sheds some light. Do you really need the same exact XML source code (something I don't think it's possible) or just an equivalent XML serialisation?

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem is that I need to have the original XML from string
>   (It is valid), with all its quotes, CDATAs etc.

XPath doesn't work on the lexical XML, it works on a tree representation of the XML after parsing. The tree representation eliminates distinctions held to be irrelevant, such as the order of attributes, the choice of single or double quotation marks, and the decision whether to escape special characters such as "&" using entity references or CDATA sections. That's deliberate policy, because it's considered that applications shouldn't care about these differences. So you may be out of luck.

But if you explain why you (think you) need access to the original lexical XML, then we may be able to find a different way of meeting that requirement.

Comment: I need original XML because it will be then parsed by another program. Values of some attributes can contain an embedded script languages, so special symbols like qoutes and ampersands should be preserved. I'm doing some kind of preprocessor that will only make some special changes to DOM.
This task is like changing text, but JQuery will make a great help with it

Comment: If the other program is using an XML parser properly, then it won't care about trivial differences like using single instead of double quotes on attributes, because the parser takes care of such differences.